# Can you take 10 when creating an item?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, skills, crafting

You can [take 10](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/usingSkills.html#taking-10-and-taking-20) when you make a skill roll *"When your character is not in immediate danger or distracted"*.

Would this include when a character is [making a magical item](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html)?

Comment: [(Note that in *D&D 3.5* there is typically no roll necessary when creating a magic item.)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80134/8610)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

There is a nice discussion of this very topic [here](http://s1.zetaboards.com/Gambit/topic/4825689/1/).

You can take 10 any time you are not rushed or distracted.  It counts as your one roll and takes no extra time.  Use this when an average roll should suffice to let you succeed, but a low roll would fail.

On the other hand, Take 20 is something to choose only if you have enough time (takes 20x as long), and when there is no significant penalty for failure (you take all penalties before you are successful).

[Taking 10 and Taking 20](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Taking-10-and-Taking-20) - from d20pfsrd

The real question is whether you have enough ranks and skill points to beat the DC for your magic item with a 10 - easy to do with lower CL items, of course.

Comment: I would also not be surprised, however, if a GM decided not to allow Take 10 for certain uses, even when a straight read of the rule book doesn't restrict the use. :)

Comment: I get the impression, after poking around a variety of forums, that the system is designed to make magic item creation easy for those that invest in feats and who have all the prerequisites.  It is also apparently designed to make the same items possible but difficult and expensive for others to create.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**,
you can take 10 on that check under normal conditions.

As opposed to taking 20, because in that case there is the additional requirements that the performed check must bear non consequence on a failed test. On the specific topic of creating a magic item, failing the check by 5 or more results in a cursed item.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, you can take 10

This has been [confirmed by a developer](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2k74y?Magic-Item-Creation-and-Caster-Level#34) at Paizo message boards:

> *Are you able to ‘take 10’ for crafting magic items?*
>
> Yes, as long as you're not distracted or in immediate danger.
>
> (...)
>
> The take 10 mechanic is in the game to prevent characters from being punished by the randomness of a d20 roll on a task that should be routine.
>
> (...)
>
> *I feel like my players who are doing crafting are getting it very easy. There is no chance for them to fail their crafting attempts at all.*
>
> That is intentional--as long as they're picking items for which they meet all the prereqs, they should have no chance of failure.

While [Sean K Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_K._Reynolds) is no longer a developer at Paizo, he was at the time of writing that message.