# Are magic item caster levels prerequisites?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting, caster-level

Every magic item has a listed caster level, which is generally listed alongside its prerequisites.  Is this listed caster level the minimum caster level required to craft the item?

For example, the item [Universal Solvent](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#universalSolvent) has a caster level of 20th, and requires the *disintegrate* spell.  What is the minimum level for a typical wizard to create this item?  Is it 20, as the caster level would indicate, or 11, when the wizard gets access to 6th level spells and cast *disintegrate*?

Comment: Related question for Pathfinder, though not a duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/is-an-items-caster-level-the-minimum-required-caster-level

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## A magic item's caster level (CL) is *not* a prerequisite for its creation

Usually *only* a magic item's prerequisites must be satisfied for the creator to create the magic item; the item's CL is a different, separate part of a magic item's entry, but a magic item's prerequisites often influence the *minimum* CL that a magic item can have.

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2003) didn't make this very clear, saying on Magic Item Descriptions on Caster Level that

> The next item in a notational entry gives the caster level of the item, indicating its relative power (just as a spell’s caster level measures its power). The caster level determines the item’s saving throw bonus, as well as range or other level-dependent aspects of the powers of the item (if variable). It also determines the level that must be contended with should the item come under the effect of a *dispel magic* spell or similar situation. This information is given in the form “CL x,” where “CL” is an abbreviation for caster level and “x” is an ordinal number representing the caster level itself.
>
> For potions, scrolls, and wands, the creator can set the caster level of an item at any number high enough to cast the stored spell and not higher than her own caster level. For example, at 5th level, Mialee could scribe a scroll of *invisibility* at caster level 3rd (making it last 3 minutes), caster level 4th (4 minutes), or caster level 5th (5 minutes).  <strike>For other magic items, the caster level is determined by the item itself. In this case, the creator’s caster level must be as high as the item’s caster level (and prerequisites may effectively put a higher minimum on the creator’s level).</strike> (215)

(Strikethrough mine.) Then the *Dungeon Master's Guide* [errata](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata) has this entry:

> #### Caster Level
>
> *Dungeon Master’s Guide*, page 215
>   **Problem:** The last two sentences in the section on Caster Level are ambiguous and potentially misleading.
>   **Solution:** Replace with this text: *For other magic items, the caster level is determined by the creator. The minimum caster level is that which is needed to meet the prerequisites given.* (1)

(Italics mine.) This erratum's folded into the two *SRDs* that I use regularly—[here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#casterLevel) and [here](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#_top)—as well as the premium edition of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2012), but this erratum is *not* present in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2003) (obviously—it's errata!) nor [here](http://darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/srd/srd_revised_html/MagicItemsI.html) in what looks like a barely modified reproduction of Wizards of the Coast's original *SRD* for *D&D 3.5e* that, so far as I can tell, is offline at its original home [here](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/srd35) but remains available *via* the *Internet Archive* [here](https://archive.org/details/dnd35srd). So, yeah, some confusion's understandable, and the erratum's author's gift for understatement hasn't gone unnoticed.

Thus, when a creator wants to create the typical magic item, the creator must meet the magic item's prerequisites. Then, prior to starting her creation, the creator sets that magic item's CL to the minimum necessary to meet the magic item's prerequisites. Since many magic items have spells as part of their prerequisites, that's usually the minimum caster level of those spells. (This minimum caster level doesn't seem to apply also to the minimum caster level necessary for meeting the appropriate item creation feat as there are many examples of [wands](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-wands), [potions](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-potions), and [wondrous items](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-wondrous-items) possessing, for example, CL 1.)

For example, while the typical magic weapon special ability [*frost*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#frost) (*DMG* 224) (+1 bonus; 0 lbs.) is printed as having CL 8, the special ability can be added to a magic weapon by a druid that meets the special ability's prerequisite *via* the 2nd-level Drd spell [*chill metal*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#chill-metal) [trans] (*PH* 209), therefore making the special ability's *minimum* CL 3. A wizard could, instead, meet the special ability's spell prerequisite with the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*ice storm*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#ice-storm) [evoc] (*PH* 243), therefore making the special ability's *minimum* CL 7. Finally, a creature possessing levels in the prestige class disciple of Thrym (*Frostburn* 56-8) could meet the special ability's spell prerequisite with the spell *ice storm*, but for that creature the spell *ice storm* is a 5rd-level spell, therefore making, in this case, the special ability's *minimum* CL 9.

Some items *will* have as prerequisites a minimum caster level, and these are *actual* prerequisites that're mandatory for the item's creation. For example, a [*ring of protection +2*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-protection) (*DMG* 232) (8,000 gp; 0 lbs.) typically has CL 5, but the *ring*'s prerequisite says that such a *ring* can only be created by a creator of at least a caster level of 6. However, the *spell* prerequisite—the 1st-level Clr spell [*shield of faith*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shield-of-faith) [abjur] (*PH* 278)—, remains unchanged, so the creator can set a *ring of protection*'s CL based on *that* spell, from 1 for a typical cleric to up to the creator's *actual* caster level.

As can be seen by these examples, designers seem to have set some magic item CLs arbitrarily.

---

### Solving the [*universal solvent*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#universal-solvent)

To be clear, the [*universal solvent*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#universal-solvent) (*DMG* 268) (50 gp; 0 lbs.) says *CL 20* then lists its prerequisites as the feat [Craft Wondrous Item](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#craft-wondrous-item) and the spell [*disintegrate*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#disintegrate). A sorcerer creator of *universal solvent* could set that CL as low as 12, a wizard creator as low as 11, a cleric that possesses the domain [Destruction](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#destruction) as low as 13, or a duskblade (*Player's Handbook II* 19-24) as low as 17. None need wait until a caster level of 20 is attained to create the *universal solvent*.

Also, readers should be aware that the *universal solvent* changed significantly during the *3.5* revision. Removed from the description of the revised *solvent* is the entire reason *why* it has such an outrageous caster level:

> If the liquid is carefully distilled to bring it down to one-third of its original volume, each dose (1/3 ounce, having been a full ounce before distillation) dissolves 1 cubic foot of organic material, just as if a *disintegrate* spell had been employed. (*Dungeon Master's Guide* (2000) 227)

(Using the *solvent* this way requires a touch attack and the subject makes a Fort save (DC 19).) Further, the original description says that even the normal, undistilled version of the older *solvent* "negates… any other form of cement, glue, or adhesive" rather than only [*sovereign glue*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#sovereign-glue) and [tanglefoot bags](http://dndsrd.net/goodsAndServices.html#tanglefoot-bag). Finally, the original *universal solvent* costs 2,000 gp. The *3.5* revision, then, changed nearly *everything* about the *universal solvent* except its prerequisites… and the CL 20.

Comment: Did 3.5 have the portion where prerequisites weren't actually necessary, but lacking them increases the DC, or was that a Pathfinder addition? I thought it existed but couldn't find it quickly.

Comment: @Ifusaso That's a *Pathfinder* thing; more about making rolls to create *3.5* magic items is covered in answers to [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80134/8610)

Answer (score 3):

The absolute minimum Caster Level needed to create an item is the minimum caster level required to cast the spell involved in the magic item's creation.

> While item creation costs are handled in detail below, note that normally the two primary factors are the caster level of the creator and the level of the spell or spells put into the item. **A creator can create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell**. ([Source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm))

If an item requires a specific caster level to create it will say so in the components, for example:

> Strong transmutation; CL 17th; Craft Wondrous Item, **creator must be
>   able to cast spells of the spell level to be recalled**; Price 1,000 gp
>   (1st), 4,000 gp (2nd), 9,000 gp (3rd), 16,000 gp (4th), 25,000 gp
>   (5th), 36,000 gp (6th), 49,000 gp (7th), 64,000 gp (8th), 81,000 gp
>   (9th), or 70,000 gp (two spells). ([Source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#pearlofPower)).

The caster level of the item listed after the aura is the caster level a random item you'd find in the world would have been created at.