# Magic Item Creation, Use Table 15-29 estimate magic item gold piece values

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

For our campaign I am trying to understand the Pathfinder crafting rules, for my alchemist tinkerer ratfolk.

skills to enable magic crafting:

- master craftsman
- craft magic arms and armor
- craft wondrous item

Skills: craft[alchemy], craft[weapon], spellcraft

**Now I am pretty confused with Table 15-29.**

For most problems (other questions) the community seems to agree that you should use the entry "weapon bonus (enhancement)" to calculate the price for weapons with common magic properties [or use Table 15-8 to look up prices in GP]

**Example:**
Mastercraft Weapon + 1 with shock
base price for magic property = + 8000           ([+1+1]^2*2000)

For which occasion do I use other entries? Only for items that cast spells, like a scroll or wand?

For example I think about some Urumi +1 with agile

Cost: +1 Bonus [CL 7, Spell Level 2 (cats grace)]

Why do you not use the base price calculated by "Spell Effect, use-activated or continous" to calculate the base price?

**Example Calculation:**
[Spell Level * Caster Level * 2000 GP*] --> 7*2*2000*(2)=56k GP

(*)-spell duration modifier

**Which part of the table do I use for what magical item?**

Comment: Hi HeryPath, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Table 15-29 is for estimating the pricing of custom Wondrous Items.  It happens to also agree with the pricing of potions and scrolls, excepting for the 'no body slot' multiplier, but it is not really intended for use with such items.  Similarly, it has a line for Weapon Bonus and a line for Armor Bonus, but otherwise those items use their own bonus-equivalent-or-fixed-price subsystem not present in the table.

Furthermore, the line 'spell effect, use activated or continuous' refers to an item that allows the used to cast a given spell, not to an item that has that spell as a crafting prerequisite.  The 'Agile' property **prerequires** *Cat's Grace*: it doesn't grant you the ability to use that spell.  You would use that line if you had, say, a spear that let you cast *scortching ray* 1/day or something.

So, to break it down:

"Single use, spell completion" should be used for scrolls and scroll-like items (like Spell Tattoos and stuff).

"Single use, use activated" should be used for potions, but also other items that have a consumable spellcasting thing, like the *Luck blade*'s *Wish* or the *Necklace of Fireballs*' *Fireball*, and potion-like things like potion sponges and cloaker magic foodstuffs.

"Weapon bonus (enhancement)" should be for weapons and things that let you enter the Magic Weapon crafting subsystem without using any actual weapons (like the *Amulet of Mighty Fists*).

"Armor bonus (enhancement)" should be for armor and things that let you enter the Magic Armor crafting subsystem without using any actual armor (like the *Bracers of Armor*).

"50 charges, spell trigger" is for wands (wondrous items have their own '50 charges' line)

And everything else is for wondrous items.

There is one entry conspicuously missing from the list, btw, which is the pricing scheme for staves.  You can find that under the section explaining how staves work.

Answer (score 0):

## Specific beats General

The Agile special weapon property has a *specific* "price", and that price is that its a "+1" weapon enchantment, and you craft/price it following those rules.

## Generally, specific magic items tell you what you need.

Take the [Agile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/agile/) special ability.  The costs are telling you:

> +1 Bonus [CL 7, Spell Level 2 (cats grace)]

1. Which means the pricing is based on the weapon enhancement table(as a +1 bonus).
2. You need CL 7 to make this item(the SRD I'm grabbing from doesn't read that way, but that distinction isn't one I care about)
3. You need the Crafts Magic Arms and Armor feat
4. You need to be able to cast Cat's Grace, or else, have an ability that "counts" for Cat's Grace somehow.

Take the [Kyton Ring](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/kyton-ring/)

1. The cost to construct is 500gp
2. You need feat Forge Ring
3. You need to be able to cast major creation
4. You need CL 7, if the SRD is being consistent with showing that requirement in the other place.

## For custom items, talk to your DM about how they should be priced.

Comment: Thx for your help. Now I am rock solid that the agile weapon will cost 8000 in addition to the weapon component and I need the right casterlevel.
The probably I can ignore the spell requirement if I add +5 to the DC.
But my major question stays!
What I still not unterstand in which situation I need the other estimates could you please give an example (or are this "options" only for crazy custom spells on Items for which I don't know the "Bonus"-Costs?).

Comment: @HeryPath 1.If an answer is useful, it should be upvoted.  2.If an answer successfully answeres the question you asked, and is the best answer, it should be accepted.  3.And most importantly, I gave an example of an item without a "bonus" cost.  Could you elaborate on what you're wanting to know there?  Is there a specific item you're confused about?

Comment: @HeryPath For caster level, while it's for *D&D 3.5e*, you may be interested in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/92430/8610); the same rules apply in *Pathfinder.*