# Creators Level Requirement for Gloves of Dexterity

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

Is there any requirement on the creators level for, say, creating Gloves of Dexterity? IE if you can create Gloves of Dexterity +2 can you also create +6 as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

You just need access to the spell Cat's Grace, the feat Craft Wondrous Items and pay the costs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no level requirement. The "caster level" labels on magic items are intended as suggestions and not as requirements. There's more on this topic in our related question: [Are magic item caster levels prerequisites?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92382/are-magic-item-caster-levels-prerequisites)