# Crafting a Cracked Dusty Rose Prism Ioun Stone - Required Creator Level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, caster-level

[Cracked Dusty Rose Prism Ioun Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/dusty-rose-prism-ioun-stone/)'s Construction Requirements seem like they may be inaccurate for the cracked and flawed versions.

It indicates the cost for all three is 2500 gp, and it indicates the required caster level for all three is 12.

According to the crafting rules, I believe the price to craft a cracked stone is 250gp in materials.

Is/should the required creator level similarly reduced for the cracked version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can only craft flawed and cracked stones by failing your check

This is was explained on the Ioun Stone creation process on [Seekers of Secrets](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8az2?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Seekers-of-Secrets-A-Guide-to-the-Pathfinder-Society) (pg. 43 and 44), more specifically, under **Cursed Ioun Stones**:

> When a magic item creation **skill check to create an ioun stone fails by 5 or more** but less than 15, there is a 50% chance the result is a cracked stone and a 50% chance the result is a flawed stone. If the check fails by 15 or more, the stone is actually cursed;

Other than that, you cannot try to create them on purpose, they are the result of failed experiments. The cost to create them, however, is the exact same of creating the perfect stone.

### Crafting requirements can be ignored

With the exception of the item creation crafting feats, **all** other [requirements can be ignored](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) if you increase the skill check DC by 5 per requirement, even if that requirement is a minimum caster level as [was noted by this FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9n8m):

> Though the listed Caster Level for a pearl of power is 17th, **that caster level is not part of the Requirements** listing for that item. Therefore, the only caster level requirement for a pearl of power is the character has to be able to cast spells of the desired level.

So, for our [Dusty Rose](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/dusty-rose-prism-ioun-stone/), the DC is 17 (5+item's CL of 12) if you have all requirements, or **DC 22** if you do not possess a caster level 12.

### Cooperating...to fail

As you might have noticed, the easiest way to fail and produce an inferior ioun stone is to purposely increase the DC and try to fail on your check.

If you really want one of those, you could craft the stone in combination with a lower level caster that does not possess the feat, so they will have to make the check with the increased DC. This assumes you are also not at caster level 12. Otherwise, you will fulfill that requirement and the DC decreases back to 17.

> It is possible for more than one character to cooperate in the creation of an item, with **each participant providing one or more of the prerequisites**. In some cases, cooperation may even be necessary.
>
> If two or more characters cooperate to create an item, they must **agree among themselves who will be considered the creator** for the purpose of determinations where the creator’s level must be known.

Should that scenario become impossible, try to find a caster with the feat and let them create it. Casting [Bestow Curse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bestow-curse/) or similar long-term debuffs is probably the easiest way to guarantee the creation of failed stones, but basically, you just need that their total skill check cannot hit 22 even on a natural 20.

### Taking 10

Finally, just like in D&D 3.5, you may also [Take 10](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Taking-10) on the skill check to create magic items in Pathfinder (as seen in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132274/21153)). This means that failing on purpose is even easier, you just gotta make sure your total bonus is +11 or less, but still above -3 so you don't produce a cursed stone. From there, it's a gamble between flawed or cracked stones (50% of each).

Also, before you try this, see [this answer about trying to intentionally fail a skill check](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49312/can-you-intentionally-fail-a-skill-check) and consult if that's ok with your GM. Some GM's are not really fine with players trying to sabbotage the rules by manipulating check results and might ask you to roll for that check even if *taking 10* would be allowed.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I did see that answer, but considering this answer is about PF, some of the references on that answer wont be applied here. Still, it's a good read.

Comment: Yeah, I will do that, Im thinking about how to properly incorporate it to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### Flawed and cracked *stones* result from failure; one does not set out to make such items

To create a flawed *ioun stone*, you have to mess up the item creation process. You expend all appropriate resources then *fail* your magic item creation skill check to create the *stone*.

[*Ioun stones*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones#TOC-Inferior-Ioun-Stones) says

> There are very few reports of *ioun stones* that have negative side effects; even those created by **incompetent item-crafters** merely create inferior specimens

and

> **Cursed Stones:** When a magic item creation skill check to create an *ioun stone* fails by 5 or more but less than 15, there is a 50% chance the result is a cracked *stone* and a 50% chance the result is a flawed *stone*. If the check fails by 15 or more, the *stone* is actually cursed; roll on Table: Common Item Curses to determine the effects of the *stone*’s curse.

Comment: I'm downvoting because I'm pretty sure that's flavor text, not rules you can act on.

Comment: @Ifusaso you think the section which talks about how failing the skill check to craft the item by a certain amount results in a cracked or flawed ioun stone is "flavor text"?

Comment: I think he is arguing about the "Incompetent item-crafter's" part of the flavor text.   There are two aspects to answering most D&D rules questions.  RAW (Rules as written) and RAI (rules as intended).   In this case I am showing that the flavor text (RAI) and the failure mechanic (RAW) both support my statement that you need to fail a crafting check to create a lesser stone.

Comment: @Ifusaso This seems totally actionable to me. (Also see [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49312/8610))

Answer (score -3):

### A caster should be 12th level or greater in order to create a Cracked, or Flawed Dusty Rose Ioun Stone.

There are *no alternate rules* for "accidentally" crafting alternate Ioun Stones by failing or otherwise, so player's should be able to make them just as they can their whole counterparts. It's simple enough to make a *less* refined product. If you feel the need, you can justify that only by being able to make the full Ioun Stone in order to be able to select an appropriate vessel for a Cracked or Flawed version.

Even if a GM rules this isn't the case, Cracked Ioun Stones can still be made at the price of their whole counterpart if they are then Broken and fixed.

One final note, *any CL crafter* can attempt to make Dusty Rose Ioun Stones or the lower counterparts. The difficulty of such a craft check is increased by 5 for ignoring a prerequisite. (Emphasis added)

> Note that all items have prerequisites in their descriptions. These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item’s creator (although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed). **The DC to create a magic item increases by 5 for each prerequisite the caster does not meet.**

Comment: The header doesn't match the content bellow, if we know there is a rule that allows us to ignore part of the requirements by increasing the DC, then the creator doesn't have to meet that requirement.

Comment: @ShadowKras I'm confused what you mean. I indicate "should" because that's what meets the Requirements. I later indicate why that's not "must"